# Break a frame into several frames

Tags: beamer, lyx

I am creating a beamer presentation with LyX. I have multiple slides (frames) that contain a lot of points - too many to fit on the slide. So I would like to break such slides into multiple slides so that all the content is visible.

I don't want to do this manually because, well, manually breaking up slides is a pain. Is there a way to break a frame into multiple frames automatically? Since `longtable` lets me break a table over several pages, I figured there should be some way of similarly breaking a frame

Tehcnical specs:

- Mac OSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite)
- LyX 2.1.2

Comment: `beamer` has the `[allowframebreaks]` option, but I have no idea how to get this into lyx. Usage: `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    something
\end{frame}`

Comment: @samcarter: that post helped me break the frame, but it did stop the overlays from working on the subsequent parts of the broken frame. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: I'm afraid, this is not possible: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41086/36296

Comment: @samcarter: is there any other way for me to get the behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: I guess you don't want to hear "by not using automatic frame breaking"? Otherwise I don't know any other way.